# How to stop JqueryTools scrollable touch

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable

I have been using [JQueryTools](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html) scrollable for a quiz, which has worked brilliantly, though the only problem I have found on iOS devices is that you can scroll by swiping to the next slide rather than using the next button which defeats the purpose of filling out a quiz, has anyone worked with this plug-in before and knows "how to turn any touch functionality off"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If you look through the source, they are utilising touchstart and touchmove and it is quite separate from the rest of the plugin, nothing depends on it, so I'd just go in there and delete that stuff maually. Shouldn't take long.</strike>

**EDIT:**

Scrap all that, just spotted this: https://raw.github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/master/src/scrollable/scrollable.js

You can set touch to false and it will disable everything.

Comment: Hey, thanks I found touchstart for example, not sure how much I should shave off, and where to stop? I don't want to bite into another function and not to javascript savvy

Comment: Check my edit, their site is out of date, the source on Git hub has the option in the config. Just set it to false.

Comment: Hi, apologies, but not sure where to implement this, I am using the original libary, and in my main.js folder I have this...

....var scrollObject = $(".scrollable").scrollable();
 var sa = scrollObject.scrollable();.......
Would I pop touch: fale in there somewhere?

Comment: Ahh found it... sorted :) just changed it to false in the jquerytools lib.js :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var scrollObject = $(".scrollable").scrollable({touch: false});
```